# StarTeam -- How do I move files programmatically?

Tags: starteam

Any StarTeam users out there?

I'm using StarTeam 2009, which comes with some client tools, including a command line tool, stcmd.exe.

I'm reorganizing a somewhat large Java project containing thousands of .java files and resource files. I would like to know if there is a way using stcmd or some other scripting tool to move files from one folder in the StarTeam repository to another folder.

Of course I can use the StarTeam client interface to drag and drop files, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stcmd gives you the ability to add, modify, and delete files and folders.  It doesn't provide a mechanism for sharing or moving.

It may be possible to do some of the moves using VCMUtility, but that's not really what it was designed for and I would guess it would end up being more of a pain than doing it by hand.

The StarTeam SDK does provide all the tools necessary to do moving and sharing.  It may be worthwhile to look into writing a small utility to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response--I'd just about given up on this. I looked into the StarTeam SDK for moving files and it wasn't very obvious which classes and methods I need to consider. Do you know what I need to look at in the SDK to move files? Thanks.

Comment: Item has the method MoveTo, which applies to both Folders and Files.  Pass a reference to the destination Folder and you should be good to go.

Comment: The SDK is the right way to handle this, BUT BE CAREFUL - you may trash the whole view! It might be better to simply drag-and-drop the files and folder that needs to be moved, considering this is a one-time effort.